# Run cmd command from inside my application

Tags: c#, cmd

I would like to make an application using C# form. Form has multiple label to show information and a button to click and show that information on that labels. All of the labels will show information which can be found using cmd. cmd will not show when program executes.

For Example:

If I need my motherboard information. It can be done using cmd commands "wmic baseboard get product,manufacturer"(without quotes). I would like to show same information on my C# form label by clicking on button. That need to be done hiding cmd windows.

Comment: You should take a look at the `Process` and `ProcessStartInfo` classes.

Comment: http://tinyurl.com/olphm2n

Comment: You can also look into just using the WMI API. [WMI.Net Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms257340%28VS.80%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ProcessStartInfo and Process classes to run this application and redirect standard output to your own method.

Setting RedirectStandardOutput will make Process raise OutputDataReceived event which you can easily handle.

P.S. Pay attention to using Arguments to provide arguments.

```
var psi = new ProcessStartInfo(@"wmic");
psi.Arguments = @"baseboard get product,manufacturer";
psi.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
psi.UseShellExecute = false;
psi.RedirectStandardOutput = true;

string val = String.Empty;

var p = Process.Start(psi);
p.BeginOutputReadLine();
p.OutputDataReceived += delegate(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs eventArgs)
{
    val += eventArgs.Data + "\r\n";
};
p.WaitForExit();

MessageBox.Show(val); // Start parsing it here
```

Answer (score 0):

Reference the code below against http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo%28v=vs.110%29.aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process(v=vs.110).aspx

```
System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo psi = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo(yourCmd, yourCmdArguments);
psi.RedirectStandardOutput = false;
psi.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
psi.UseShellExecute = true;
System.Diagnostics.Process externalProcess;
externalProcess = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(psi);
externalProcess.WaitForExit();
```